# MongoDB aggregate, geNear and iterate over callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreach, geolocation, aggregate

I have a problem and I can´t find a solution. I have some MongoSchemas where I store Geolocation from users. Mobile Phone is sending me longitude and latitude every 5 minutes. This API is working perfectly.

Mongo-Schema looks like:

```
    // Importing Node packages required for schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//= ===============================
// User Schema
//= ===============================
const GeolocationSchema = new Schema({
  loc: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' }
  },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
},
  {
    timestamps: true
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Geolocation', GeolocationSchema);
```

Now, I want to calculate users-nearby which have an "updateAt"-timestamp not even longer than 5 minutes in the past. That means that one or more users can be in a distance of e.g. 500m until 5 minutes in the past. This should be a match. For this I use Mongo aggregate, and I want to iterate the callback-result and extract the user._id out of the result to build a match.

This is what I tried:

```
const Geolocation = require('../models/geolocation')
User = require('../models/user'),    
config = require('../config/main');

exports.setGeolocation = function (req, res, next) {
// Only return one message from each conversation to display as snippet
 console.log(req.user._id);

var geoUpdate = Geolocation.findOneAndUpdate( { user: req.user._id },
      { loc: {      
        type: 'Point', 
        coordinates: req.body.coordinates.split(',').map(Number)
      },
      user: req.user._id
      },
      {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true}, // options
      function (err, doc) { // callback
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
          } 
      });

// create dates for aggregate query
var toDate = new Date( (new Date()).getTime());
var fromDate = new Date( (new Date()).getTime() - 5000 * 60 );    

var match = Geolocation.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
       near: { 
             type: "Point",
             coordinates: req.body.coordinates.split(',').map(Number)
             },
       distanceField: "dist.calculated",
       maxDistance: 500,        
       includeLocs: "dist.location",
       uniqueDocs: true,
       query: { user: {$ne: req.user._id } , updatedAt: { $gte: fromDate,$lte: toDate }},            
       num: 5,
       spherical: true
    }
  }], function (err, doc){


    //here I´m going in trouble correctly parsing doc

    var str = JSON.stringify(doc);
    var newString = str.substring(1, str.length-1);                 
    var response = JSON.parse(newString);

    console.log(response.user);

  });      

  res.sendStatus(200);  
};
```

As you can see I´m going in trouble in parsing the "doc"-callback to iterate over the documents. If I want to parse it as jSON I´m getting an token-error on position 1. If I have more than 2 results, I´m getting an error on position 288.

That´s why I tried to parse and stringify the "doc". But this is not working correctly.

Maybe, someone could help me with a solution. I´m not familiar with mongo-functions because I´m starting with it, maybe there is a better solution but I can´t find something else to calculate geoNear and iterate afterwards over the results.

Thx at all who can help...